# Countable fundamental system of neighbourhoods in a compact Hausdorff space?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Is it true (or false) that every point in a compact Hausdorff-Space has a countable local base, i.e. a countable fundamental system of neighbourhoods?
If this is false, which additional property (except metrizability) would ensure the above conclusion?

Comment: It's false; one simple counterexample is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1318812/12042). I don't offhand know of any natural sufficiently condition other than metrizability.

Comment: The second countability axiom is very stringent. Every metrizable Lindel\"{o}f space has a countable basis.

Comment: @Jacob: But the question is about first countability. Of course second countability implies that, but in this context it also implies metrizability.

Comment: Note that in a compact Hausdorff space, if there is a coutable local pseudobase at a point, then there is a countable local base at that point. A pseudobase at a point is a colection of open sets such that its intersection is just that point.

Comment: Another counterexamples should be Tychonoff cube $[0,1]^\lambda$ or Cantor cube $\{0,1\}^\lambda$ with uncountable $\lambda$ or the space $[0,\omega_1]$ of ordinals endowed with an order topology.